# Copy Folding Group

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, html

Id like to copy the contents from HTML for a certain html-element and all the inner elements via notepad++.

I know ctrl+B in Notepad++ from here: [Notepad++: Select/Copy Collapsed Folding Group](https://superuser.com/questions/444448/notepad-select-copy-collapsed-folding-group) but it only works for curly braces and not for html tags...

E.g. code:

```
<div class="portlet-title">
    <div class="caption">
        <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>Form Sample
    </div>
    <div class="tools">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse">
        </a>
        <a href="#portlet-config" data-toggle="modal" class="config">
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="reload">
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="remove">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to somehow "select" the code `<div class="tools">` and via shorcut copy this element with all its subnodes, in this case:

```
    <div class="tools">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse">
        </a>
        <a href="#portlet-config" data-toggle="modal" class="config">
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="reload">
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="remove">
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for publishing the solution! maybe you can convert it into an answer and accept it afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the HTML Tag Plugin in notepad++ via Shift+Ctrl+T to select a HTML Tag until its closing tag, see

Notepad++ Jump between opening and closing html tags